# Creating a new Android project in Eclipse ADT gives a NullPointerException — Mac OS X

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I am using Eclipse ADT and I am unable to create a new Android project. Just a few days ago, it worked perfectly. Now, when I try to create a new Android project and click finish, it gives me a pop-up with the following text:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'MyApp'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

I have tried the following:

• Reinstalling Eclipse

• Downloading updates

• Changing the workspace

• Deleting and reinstalling the Android Support Library

I am no longer able to create new Android projects. I am desperate for help.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

project->properties->android->choose & set the "project build target".

and after that build your project.

Hope it help.

Comment: cant select "android"  options  eclipse luna  throws  errors  saying "The currently displayed page contains invalid values"